# Can I say that the Liouville's theorem is an "analytic property" of complex numbers?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I am a second language learner and run into some issues about language.

Liouville's theorem in complex analysis states that every holomorphic function defined on the whole complex plane is either constant or unbounded. Note that the word "holomorphic" is a concept in analysis, so can I say that this theorem is an "analytic property" of complex numbers.

I cannot call this "topological property" because there are no derivatives in topology.

Similar confusion appears for the phrases "geometric property", "algebraic property".

Could anyone give an example for each of those "properties"? You know, for abstract things like complex numbers (I do know there is complex geometry, but why it is called "geometry"?) or Banach spaces, I have no idea what "geometry" means.

Comment: You probably meant *“either constant or **un**bounded”*

Comment: I would say it is a property of complex functions rather than complex numbers.

Comment: @Klaus: more precisely, *holomorphic* functions rather than complex functions.

Comment: It is *un*bounded. It must reach the infinity point at infinity.

Comment: Sorry. I have made a stupid mistake.